# Call a Razor Page Post method, Using Ajax for popup delete confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, post, razor-pages

I want to use JQuery UI Dialog to confirm my delete action, I tried some tutorial on the internet but I still having trouble to call OnPost delete action page, when click on delete  confirm button
when I run the project It doesn't call my post method :

I have a razor page method (I just copied part of the code that has relation) :

```
    public class DeleteUserModel : PageModel
       {
        
          public InformationUserViewModel InformationUser { get; set; }
          public void OnGet(int id)
           {
              ViewData["UserId"] = id;
              InformationUser = _userService.GetUserInformation(id);
           }
   
       public IActionResult OnPost(int userId)
           {
            _userService.DeleteUser(userId);
             return RedirectToPage("Index");
           }
     }
```

Index page with delete button on it:

```
       @page
       @model Fraud.Pages.Admin.IndexModel

      <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirm('@user.UserName', '@user.UserId')" />
```

in this page I have popup view :

```
                   <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <span>
                            Are you sure you want to delete?
                        </span>
                        <strong id="deletedValueName">
                        </strong>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"  onclick="deleteData()" />
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

And at last my jquery ajax :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  
              var deleteConfirm = function (val,id) {
               $('#deletedValueName').text(val);
               $('#id').val(id);

              $('#delete-conformation').modal('show');
              }

    
      var deleteData = function () {
        $('#divLoading').show();
        var id =  $('#id').val();
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/Users/DeleteUser?handler=Send",
          // url: '/Admin/Users/DeleteUser/OnPost',
           data: { UserId: id },
          success: function (result) {
              $("#delete-conformation").modal('hide');
        },
            error: function () {
            $("#delete-conformation").modal('hide');
        }
    });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: "It doesn't call my post method" Have  you use the F12 to see  the error message in the console ?

Comment: Yea I get 404 error

Comment: According to your"  url: "/Admin/Users/DeleteUser?handler=Send",  "     Change your handler name , like : "public IActionResult OnPostSend(int userId)"

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX calls *"/Admin/Users/DeleteUser?handler=Send"*. Therefore, you handler needs to be called `OnPostSend()` or `OnPostSendAsync()`.

Your handler is called `OnPost()` so it wasn't found.